# Can't run image on AWS EC2 VM error: docker run standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"

Tags: python, docker, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to run an image with this command: `docker run -p 5000:80 kareemamrr/deepspeaker:cpu-v1` and with this dockerfile

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:2.3.1

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get upgrade -y \
    && apt-get install -y \
    && apt-get -y install apt-utils gcc libpq-dev libsndfile-dev

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["uvicorn", "api:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

But I'm thrown this error, it works perfectly as expected on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

What type of AWS EC2 instance are you using? It seems that you have platform incompatible executables, like in you are building an image for x86 and running on an ARM instance.
I that's the case check this:
https://www.docker.com/blog/multi-arch-build-and-images-the-simple-way/